# Borceux' Handbook of Categorical Algebra I. Proposition 4.4.3.

Tags: category-theory

Borceux defines "finitely well-complete" as a category such that it is finitely complete and the intersection of any class of subobjects exists. He then proceeds to give the following proof:

[image]

It seems to me however that, at least as it is, the proof is wrong. The compatible family $p_k$ factors through each $i_k$ indeed, but I don't think it follows that there must be a $p:A \to I$ as indicated. Since $I$ is the limit in the category of subobjects, so for this argument to work the $p_k$ should be such that $i_k \circ p_k$ are mono (for example requiring that the $p_k$ are mono too).

Is this argument indeed wrong, or am I missing something? If not, is there a way to fix this argument?

(Note that if the limit of the $i_k$ exists it must coincide with the intersection $i$, but I don't see why this limit should exist given the asssumptions).

Comment: Good question... Maybe I is meant to be the wide pullback, not the intersection.

Comment: How are intersections defined in the book?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Intersections are defined as "the infimum in the category of subobjects".

Answer (score 2):

The intersection of some family of subobjects $(\lambda_j:K_j\hookrightarrow X)_{j\in J}$ is defined as the pullback of all the $\lambda_\bullet$, call it $\lambda:K\hookrightarrow X$ (well-defined up to subobject equivalence). However, this pullback is computed in the same category that $X,K_\bullet$ live in, it is not computed in the category of subobjects. *However*, once you do compute the pullback $\lambda:K\hookrightarrow X$ it will also be true that $\lambda$ is a pullback in the category of subobjects (I doubt the converse implication would hold true in general).

Anyway, $i$ is, by the sensible definitions of "intersection of subobject" that I've seen, the ordinary pullback. If this is accepted it is then very easy to see $p$ exists and exists uniquely in the described way.

N.B. The concept of intersection that I use in this is the same that appears in the Mac Lane's proof of the special adjoint functor theorem. This is, I suppose, more evidence that this is a sensible notion.

Comment: Interesting! I didn't know there was another (and in fact possibly more standard) definition for intersection. It seems the [nlab agrres with Borceux](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/subobject) though in the case of well-powered co(complete) categories these notions agree. I guess I'm interested in this converse you mention.